# ffmpeg drawbox on a given frame

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, frame

I have thousands of rectangle boxes to add in a video. Right now I am using this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i small.ts -vf drawbox=10:10:50:50:red,drawbox=100:100:200:200:green small_with_box.ts
```

However I don't want to add the boxes on an entire frame, but on a given one. Anyone know how can I do that?

Answer (score 20):

The [`drawbox`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) video filter has [timeline editing](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) support. You can see what filters support timeline editing:

```
$ ffmpeg -filters
…
Filters:
  T. = Timeline support
  .S = Slice threading
  A = Audio input/output
  V = Video input/output
  N = Dynamic number and/or type of input/output
  | = Source or sink filter
…
 .. deshake          V->V       Stabilize shaky video.
 T. drawbox          V->V       Draw a colored box on the input video.
 T. drawgrid         V->V       Draw a colored grid on the input video.
```

You can see that `drawbox` and `drawgrid` have timeline support, but `deshake` currently does not.

Usage example. This will place the red box from frames 28-32, and the green box starting at 60 seconds. Also see the documentation on expression evaluations for additional functions.

```
ffmpeg -i small.ts -vf "drawbox=enable='between(n,28,32)' : x=10 : y=10 : w=50 \
: h=50 : color=red,drawbox=enable='gte(t,60)' : x=100 : y=100 : w=200 : \
h=200 : color=green" -codec:a copy small_with_box.ts
```

Comment: Expression Evaluation documentation https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Expression-Evaluation