# Create muted video and black screen video with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to generate the following from a local mp4 file:

- A copy of the original video with no audio
- A copy of the original video with audio but without visuals (a black screen instead). This file also needs to be in mp4 format.

After reading through the documentation I am struggling to get the terminal commands right. To remove the audio I have tried this command without any success:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -acodec copy -vcodec copy
```

Could anyone guide me towards how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Create black video and silent audio

Use the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#allrgb_002c-allyuv_002c-color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc_002c-testsrc2_002c-yuvtestsrc) and [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) filters. Example to make 10 second output, 1280x720, 25 frame rate, stereo audio, 44100 sample rate:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=1280x720:rate=25:color=black -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -t 10 output.mp4
```

## Remove audio

Only keep video:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -c copy output.mp4
```

Keep everything except audio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -map -0:a -c copy output.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) for more info on `-map`.

## Make video black but keep the audio

Using the [drawbox](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) filter.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf drawbox=color=black:t=fill -c:a copy output.mp4
```

## Generate silent audio

See [How to add a new audio (not mixing) into a video using ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783474/) and refer to the anullsrc example.

Comment: What if you only want to draw a black box between 10 and 20 seconds? Thanks!

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Adapt [ffmpeg drawbox on a given frame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17354683/).

Answer (score 2):

To remove the [audio](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options) you can use this:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -c copy -an file-nosound.mp4
```

notice the `-an` option

> -an (output)
>      Disable audio recording.

To keep audio but "replace" the video with a black screen, you could do this:

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex overlay out.mp4
```

`image.png` is a black wallpaper that is placed on top of the video, but there should be better ways of full removing the frames, you could either extract the audio and later create a new video with the audio as a background

Comment: Thanks for this. For any future readers, `-filter_complex overlay` was about 3 times faster for me than `-vf geq=0:128:128`