# Blank out video frames for last two minutes of MP4 (while keeping audio intact)

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to make a copy of one of my mp4 movies with audio intact, but blacking out video frames only on the last few minutes. Basically I want to keep the end credit music but without the artifacted video.

I found [this answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370114/10860467) which works perfectly for an entire mp4 file  (including a test fragment I made of the above ending credits sequence), but I need it applied as I stated above to just the end of the entire copied full mp4.

In this case I don't want to start blanking the video stream frames until after 2h 7m 30s. I messed around with combinations of the **-ss**, **-start_time** and **-timecode 02:07:31** params, but I'm an ffmpeg noob and couldn't get it to produce anything but cut-out sections or the whole copy blanked.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the drawbox filter to black those frames out.

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf drawbox=c=black:t=fill:enable='gt(t\,7650)' -c:a copy out
```

This will black out the frames from 7650 seconds onwards.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. A question: does the drawbox filter cause the copy streams function to perform a transcode? I noticed that the processing was quite a bit slower, and the out file was smaller than just the main segment that I had split out at 2:07:30.

Comment: Yes, use of any filter means that stream can't be copied.